# make my page look good while resizing... using width 80%

Tags: html, css

My page uses the .css `position:absolute`; and percentage height attributes, eg. `height 80%;` .  It looks great when its full screen but it look terrible when its minimized.  When its minimized I would like to get a scrollbar.  Is there someway to have an element be 80% width of the screen when the screen is maximized, but if the screen is resized, then maintain the initial size and get a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using the `min-height` attribute will help?  This should prevent the 80% height from shrinking indefinitely and allow you to specify an `overflow` attribute to get the scrollbars.